# Adding an Item to QGraphicsItemGroup Makes It Invisible

Tags: c++, qt

The code below

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse = addEllipse(x, y, 6, 6, series_pen);
ellipse->translate(-ellipse->boundingRect().width() / 2,
                   -ellipse->boundingRect().height() / 2);
ellipse->setToolTip(label);
```

draws the `QGraphicsEllipseItem` on a `QGraphicsScene`. However, the following code doesn't:

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse = addEllipse(x, y, 6, 6, series_pen);
ellipse->translate(-ellipse->boundingRect().width() / 2,
                   -ellipse->boundingRect().height() / 2);
ellipse->setToolTip(label);

QGraphicsItemGroup *g = new QGraphicsItemGroup;
g->addToGroup(ellipse);
```

What is wrong if I add a `QGraphicsItem` in `QGraphicsItemGroup`?

I'm using Qt Creator 2.2.1, Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Qt manual page for **[QGraphicsItemGroup](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitemgroup.html)**:

> There are two ways to construct an item group. The easiest and most
>   common approach is to pass a list of items (e.g., all selected items)
>   to QGraphicsScene::createItemGroup(), which returns a new
>   QGraphicsItemGroup item. The other approach is to manually construct a
>   QGraphicsItemGroup item, add it to the scene calling
>   QGraphicsScene::addItem(), and then add items to the group manually,
>   one at a time by calling addToGroup().

Sounds like your code needs to call QGraphicsScene::addItem().

Answer (score 4):

`QGraphicsItemGroup` is also a `QGraphicsItem`, so you need to add it to the scene, for its children to be drawn too.